# Why does my Python POST request lead me to the initial webpage?

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests, request

I am new to this Forum and relatively new to coding

This question has already been asked here but the solutions didn't seem to work for me.

I'd like to log into the index.php page using a Python Post request, but the response url remains the same with the intitial login page indicating that the login was not successful.

```
import requests as r

login_url = "https://www.example.com/index.php?login"
index_url = "https://www.example.com/gymla/index.php" #The url I want to be directed to

data = {
    "isiwebuserid": "username",
    "isiwebpasswd": "password",
    "submit": "Senden"
}

s = r.session()
response = s.post(login_url, data=data)

print(response.url)
if response.url == login_url:
    print("The attempt did not work.")
```

I've checked with <form action if the login URL might be wrong, but it seems alright. The form data is also complete. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Have you examined the response page content to see if it mentions what is wrong? 
 Perhaps there is a missing CSRF token?

Comment: Also, have you tried doing a GET on that page first?  If you start off with a POST, that doesn't give the page a chance to set any cookies, which it may depend on.

Comment: @JohnGordon POST didn't really help and while I don't really understand about CSRF Token I couldn't really find any error message about it. But you made me think that the form value "submit"  is a button and not a text. Do you think the problem could be related to me posting it as some form of text data when it's actually a button?

Comment: The only other difference I see is that the value of the submit button on the form is "Submit", not "Senden" (although maybe that's due to localization?)

Answer (score 0):

Url does not change but remains fixed, Try this

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("The attempt did not work.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for answering my question. The solution was indeed to use *"Submit"* instead of *"Senden"*.